# Non-uniform contraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A map $f: X \longrightarrow X$ is called *contracting* if there exists a $\lambda < 1$ such that for any $x, y \in X$

$$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq \lambda d(x,y)$$

It is well known that a contracting map $f$ on a complete metric space has a unique fixed point to which all points converge under interation by $f$.

In Katok's and Hasselblatt's *Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems*, there is an exercise designed to show the importance of the uniform contraction condition in the definition of contracting maps, that is, to show the importance of the existence of a $\lambda$ strictly less than $1$ that works for **all** $x, y \in X$. The question is as follows:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Construct an example of a map $f:X \longrightarrow X$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ for $x \neq y$, $f$ has no fixed point, and $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))$ does **not** converge to zero for some $x,y \in X$.

I've been having a lot of trouble keeping everything in check: $X$ complete, no fixed point, and also the existence of some pair $x,y$ for which the distance between iterates does not go to $0$. Are any examples of this highly pathological or am I missing something simple?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

surface $r = 1 + e^{-z}$ in cylindrical coordinates. Map is just $z \mapsto 1 + z,$ that is
$$ ( ( 1 + e^{-z}) \cos \theta,  ( 1 + e^{-z}) \sin \theta, z ) \mapsto   ( ( 1 + e^{-z -1}) \cos \theta,  ( 1 + e^{-z-1}) \sin \theta, z +1 )   $$

Or, intersection of the same thing with the $xz$ plane, easier, and the proofs become easier. No apparent requirement for connectivity.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, and sheds some light into the process behind it. Thank you.