# Counterexample for a weakened definition of contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

I was trying to solve this exercise form a book on dynamical systems. There, after introducing the notion of contraction mapping, it is shown that, given a complete metric space $(X,d)$  and a contraction mapping $f:X\to X$, there exists a unique point $p\in X$ s.t. $f(p)=p$ and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f^n(x)=p$$
for all $x\in X$ (here $f^n$ represents the $n-$th iterate of the map).

After that, a problem ask the reader to find essentially a counterexample of this result in case the definition of contraction mapping is weakened. Specifically

> Construct an example of a map $f:X\to X$ (where $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space) such that
>
> - $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for $x\neq y$
> - $f$ has no fixed points
> - $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))$ does not converge to zero for some $x,y$.

I tried to construct an example in $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ and I managed to satisfy the first two conditions, but not the third.

My attempt was the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}.$$
Since $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there are no fixed points, and since
we have that
$$d(f(x),f(y))=\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1+y^2}\right|=\left|\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right|<\left|\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x+y}\right|=|x-y|=d(x,y)\ .$$
However, since its iterates are
$$f^n(x)=\sqrt{n+x^2}\ ,$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f^n(x)-f^n(y))=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\sqrt{n+x^2}-\sqrt{n+y^2}\right)=0$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to see how to construct a function satisfying all three conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: One answer is [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/940891/81360).

Comment: As a modification to the answer given in the above link: take
$$
X = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : xy = 1, \quad x > 0\}.
$$
Define $f:X \to X$ by
$$
f(x,\frac 1x) = (x+1,\frac 1{x+1}). 
$$
Equivalently,
$$
f(x,y) = (x+1,\frac y{y+1}).
$$